# Extends User plugin by adding a profile does not render tab either new added fields in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, octobercms

I've follow all the steps on the [Extending User plugin](http://vimeo.com/108040919) screencast but for some reason I can not see "Profile" tab and either new added fields. Since I used the second approach, the easy one, this is what I've done:

- Create the plugin and models and so on under Alomicuba namespace
- Create and make the needed changes to the files as explained in video:

  ```
  Plugin.php

  <?php namespace Alomicuba\Profile;

  use System\Classes\PluginBase;
  use RainLab\User\Models\User as UserModel;
  use RainLab\User\Controllers\Users as UsersController;

  /**
   * Profile Plugin Information File
   */
  class Plugin extends PluginBase
  {
      public $requires = ['RainLab.User'];

      /**
       * Returns information about this plugin.
       *
       * @return array
       */
      public function pluginDetails()
      {
          return [
              'name'        => 'Profile',
              'description' => 'Add extra functionalities for Alomicuba WS by extends RainLab User',
              'author'      => 'DTS',
              'icon'        => 'icon-users'
          ];
      }

      public function boot()
      {
          UserModel::extend(function($model){
              $model->hasOne['profile'] = ['Alomicuba\Profile\Models\Profile'];
          });

          UsersController::extendFormFields(function ($form, $model, $context){
              if ($model instanceof UserModel)
                  return;

              $form->addTabFields([
                  'pinCode' => [
                      'label' => 'PIN',
                      'tab' => 'Profile'
                  ],
                  'phone2' => [
                      'label' => 'Teléfono (2)',
                      'tab' => 'Profile'
                  ],
                  'phone3' => [
                      'label' => 'Teléfono (3)',
                      'tab' => 'Profile'
                  ],
                  'phone4' => [
                      'label' => 'Teléfono (4)',
                      'tab' => 'Profile'
                  ]
              ]);
          });
      }
  }

  add_profiles_fields_to_user_table.php

  <?php namespace Alomicuba\Profile\Updates;

  use Schema;
  use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;

  class AddProfilesFieldsToUserTable extends Migration
  {

      public function up()
      {
          Schema::table('users', function($table)
          {
              $table->integer('pinCode')->unsigned();
              $table->dateTime('pinCodeDateTime');
              $table->integer('phone2')->unsigned()->nullable();
              $table->integer('phone3')->unsigned()->nullable();
              $table->integer('phone4')->unsigned()->nullable();
          });
      }

      public function down()
      {
          $table->dropDown([
              'pinCode',
              'pinCodeDateTime',
              'phone2',
              'phone3',
              'phone4'
          ]);
      }
  }

  version.yaml
  1.0.1: First version of Profile
  1.0.2:
      - Created profiles table
      - create_profiles_table.php
      - add_profiles_fields_to_user_table.php

  Profile.php (Model)
  <?php namespace Alomicuba\Profile\Models;

  use Model;

  /**
   * Profile Model
   */
  class Profile extends Model
  {
      /**
       * @var string The database table used by the model.
       */
      public $table = 'alomicuba_profile_profiles';

      /**
       * @var array Relations
       */
      public $belongsTo = [
          'user' => ['RainLab\User\Models\User']
      ];


      // This method is not need anymore since I'll use the second approach
      public static function getFromUser($user)
      {
          if ($user->profile)
              return $user->profile;

          $profile = new static;
          $profile->user = $user;
          $profile->save();

          $user->profile = $profile;

          return $profile;
      }
  }
  ```

But when I edit a existent user I didn't see the 'Profile' tab and also didn't see any new added field. See image below:

[image]

Any advice around this? Did I miss something?

Also I have a few question around plugin extends:

1. How do I add a required field to the register form?
2. How do I display each new added field on the account form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haved tested your code on my machine you need to write

`$require` instead of `$requires` in plugin.php

please check documentation

http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#dependency-definitions

and when extendFormFields() method called for UserController you need to specify that you only want to extends fields for UserModel not for other

```
if (!$model instanceof UserModel)
    return;
```

so plugin.php code look like this

```
<?php namespace Alomicuba\Profile;

use System\Classes\PluginBase;
use RainLab\User\Models\User as UserModel;
use RainLab\User\Controllers\Users as UsersController;

/**
 * Profile Plugin Information File
 */
class Plugin extends PluginBase
{
    public $require = ['RainLab.User'];

    /**
     * Returns information about this plugin.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function pluginDetails()
    {
        return [
            'name'        => 'Profile',
            'description' => 'Add extra functionalities for Alomicuba WS by extends RainLab User',
            'author'      => 'DTS',
            'icon'        => 'icon-users'
        ];
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        UserModel::extend(function($model){
            $model->hasOne['profile'] = ['Alomicuba\Profile\Models\Profile'];

        });

        UsersController::extendFormFields(function ($form, $model, $context){
            if (!$model instanceof UserModel)
                return;

            $form->addTabFields([
                'pinCode' => [
                    'label' => 'PIN',
                    'tab' => 'Profile'
                ],
                'phone2' => [
                    'label' => 'Teléfono (2)',
                    'tab' => 'Profile'
                ],
                'phone3' => [
                    'label' => 'Teléfono (3)',
                    'tab' => 'Profile'
                ],
                'phone4' => [
                    'label' => 'Teléfono (4)',
                    'tab' => 'Profile'
                ]
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

and in add_profiles_fields_to_user_table.php

for dropping column write following code

```
Schema::table('users', function($table)
{
        $table->dropDown([
            'pinCode',
            'pinCodeDateTime',
            'phone2',
            'phone3',
            'phone4'
        ]);
}
```

Comment: I think `dropDown` has been renamed to `dropColumn` in the recent versions of laravel.